# Joomla search URL Issue

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

This the site - http://www.anesthesiallc.com/

It is joomla 3.6

In my scenario we have menu called communique (Publication-->communique )

Click any link like Fall 2016 , Summer 2016 - 
**[The Perioperative Surgical Home: Invest in Good Will](http://www.anesthesiallc.com/publications/communique/93-communique/current-issue/communique-fall-2016/964-the-perioperative-surgical-home-invest-in-good-will)**

It works fine. But if i search keyword - The Perioperative Surgical Home.

I got a result. But if i click the link it not going.

Note : Error page or 4o4 page goes to Home page only.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the searched title it goes to the right article but "publications/communique/" is missing from the URL (after domain.com/). Create a hidden menu for search (menu type: search) so the search results will be shown in the search component page instead of home page and the URL problem may be fixed.